# Flutter iOS app starts on iPhone only from Android Studio

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, android-studio, dart

I can run my app many times in row on iPhone (real device) using 'run' in Android Studio.Everything works fine, but if I close the app and click on icon in the iPhone, it's crashed before the splash screen.

Why I can't start it from the device?

Answer (score 1):

If you run your app on the iPhone in debug mode, it won't run after the debug session is terminated. You can run the up from command line in release mode on the iPhone, so you can start the app event if there is no active debug:

```
flutter run --release
```